# How to implement a template function returning a vector from the template argument?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way (in C++ 11) to implement the following method:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> makeTypedVector(void* array, int n)
{
    //construct an std::vector of type T from the given array
}
```

I would share what I've tried but I have no clue on how to implement it :)

**Edit:**

Is the same method possible for arrays instead of std::vector?

**Edit2:**

Usage:
We're storing tuples of (void* array,Type). I need to be able to compare two elements of the same data type. therefore, I want to convert the void* array into a typed vector in order to know how to compare between two elements

Comment: Why can't you use an initializer list, e.g. `vector<int> v = { 1, 4, }`?  EDIT: can you show some example uses?  Imagine somebody has written the perfect makeTypedVector() function for you; what would you do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do the following to create a vector which is a copy of the given array:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> makeTypedVector(void* array, int n)
{
    const T* a = reinterpret_cast<T*>(array);
    return {a, a + n};
}
```

But it seems strange that you get a `void*` first.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use the same buffer for the vector instead of copying it?

Comment: @Shmoopy: `std::vector` is not designated for that. You may create a class `Range` which take the 2 given pointers/iterators (`a`, `a+n`) and work with that.